# What is a good "non-hacky" way to pass a value from JSP to javascript in a specific scenario

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

So, here we go guys, my team is working on a big java web application, it has a lot of legacy code. The way the previous team that worked on the application used to pass variables from JSP to javascript was compiling all the .js files as .jsp

In the beggining of the javascript file, it would include (commentated javascript code that would render as java code) a file that opens a `<script>` tag and does some importing, and in the end of the file it would include a jsp file that closes the tag.

Something like this in a javascript file:

```
/* <%@ include file="init.jsp" %> */

real javascript code here

/* <%@ include file="end.jsp" %> */
```

So we could call the script file like this in some random jsp:

`<script src='whatever.js?param=<%=parameter%>'></script>`

And so we could get a parameter from the url since in reality it is a jsp

`var x = "<%=UtilitiesWeb.getParameterFromUrl('param')%>"`

And everyone agrees that it's a really bad practise.

So, I want a better way to this, but I also have some restrictions. Look at the following scenario.

I have this jsp:

```
<%
final String id = (String) request.getAttribute("id");
%>

<div id="<%=id>">
<script src="whatever.js"></script>
```

Basically, I need the whatever.js to get the java variable id so I can do some modifications in the div (in my case, the div is going to be a grid with some data populated by the avascript). But, I **can't** do something like this:

```
<script src="whatever.js" data-customattribute="<%=id>"></script>

// Inside the javascript file
var id = $("script[data-customattribute]").attr("data-customattribute")
```

The reason I can't do this is because this my jsp is called in many places assynchronously, so I can't guarantee I'm getting the ID related to the js file. I don't think that getting the .last() script with the attribute would be reliable either, since the app has many javascript files called assynchronously (but it could be, so if anyone has more understanding about this please say it).

I also tried using document.currentScript but it returned null, not sure why?

I was thinking of using a `<object>` block to call the jsp file with javascript (or maybe the only the javascript, not sure if this works), so the javascript would only have acess to the div inside the object, and it would not be confused with any other divs inside the document, but I've heard there are some drawbacks to using things like `<object>` or `<iframe>`.

So...any ideas/tips/advices? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: If you are just try to pass a value from JSP (server side) to the client side JavaScript, then why not write it directly inside JavaScript, like `<script> if (id) {id = "<%=id>;"} else (var id = "<%=id>;") </script>`.

Answer (score 0):

The way we'd always done it is to have the scripts simply define functions, then you can embed function calls directly in your JSP like so:

```
<% final String id = (String) request.getAttribute("id"); %>
<script src="whatever.js"></script>

<div id="<%=id>"></div>
<script>whatever("<%=id>")</script>
```

It seems easier to debug that way, and you can statically serve the script files.

As an aside, and if you're able, I'd recommend you look at Apache Velocity to replace the JSP layer. It makes life nicer :)